# how to find the distribution and parameter given normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, sampling, chi-squared

given that $K_{1}$, $K_{2}$, ... , $K_{n}$ is a random variables from a normal distribution with $μ$ = 10, $σ^2$ = 2.5

what is the distribution and parameter for $X$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \left(\frac{K_{i} - 10}{\sqrt{2.5}}\right)$ ?

is $x̄$~$N$(10,0.25) the right answer ? or do i need to use the chi-square distribution ?

Comment: Your $X =  \sum_{i=1}^{10}Z_i$ with $\mu_X = E(X) = 0$ and (provided $K_i$ are independent)  $\sigma_X^2 = 10(1)=10.$ Thus $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma=\sqrt{10}).$ If you want $\sum_{i=1}^{10}Z_i^2,$ then you have $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=10),$ which has variance 20.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

Knowing that: $K_{j} \sim N(10,2.5), \forall j \in {1,2,..,n}$

We want to determinate the distribution of
\begin{equation*}
X = \sum_{i=1}^{10} (\frac{K_{i}-10}{\sqrt{2.5}})
\end{equation*}
Please note that for each $\underline{i}$,  $$\frac{K_{i}-10}{\sqrt{2.5}}\sim N(0,1)$$
So, rewriting X, we have:
\begin{equation*}
X = Z_{1} + Z_{2} + ... + Z_{10}, \text{ where } Z_{i} \sim N(0,1), i \in {1,2,...,10}
\end{equation*}
Now, if the variables are independent, you get a sum of Normal Distributed variables which is a Normal Distributed Variable.

You could use the Chi-Square distribution if the standard Z variables were squared up, this is, if:
\begin{align*}
X = \sum_{i=1}^{10} (\frac{K_{i}-10}{\sqrt{2.5}})^{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: if i squared up the U, wouldn't the answer become standard normal chi square distribution ? ~X 2 and 1

Comment: Each of the U variable would be a standard chi square distribution. But the sum of them would be $\sim X 2 and 10$.